# adjust text in the center with position dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Using this code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( dat,aes(x=factor(group),y=difference) ) +
  geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(Mutation)),stat="identity",
            position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Mutation),position=position_dodge(height=0.9),angle=90)+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I generate the flowing plot. As you see some text are not in the center of the bars. I tried some options like `hjust` , `vjust` or playing with `dodge width`, without success. Can someone help me get the text in the center of bars?

In the plot below we have problem with group = 1 ,3,8,9,...

[image]

Here my data :

```
dat <-  structure(list(Mutation = structure(1:21, .Label = c("2rN7y", 
"2wTys", "8ElEj", "8esgR", "8ppm9", "BkuXt", "bM5sv", "c7KTn", 
"dnBl6", "F5nhO", "fFpM6", "hMpSW", "HxAh9", "KDI0t", "qZTSa", 
"rOONr", "Tf2kX", "TGDZE", "tLdje", "XsGz6", "XTGN1"), class = "factor"), 
    difference = c(2.1499193357556, 0.27602347826589, -0.22889581513082, 
    -0.77297822818092, -0.468200478640476, -0.735026155784277, 
    -0.900791750580477, -1.33435362820732, 0.412022274758476, 
    0.495870479997156, 0.793585307678721, 1.22839278213642, -1.0700682293443, 
    0.63436212480624, -0.152410633064764, 1.23397624015726, -0.520869343832941, 
    1.62320252173067, -0.24168976773895, -1.04897550447309, 1.68588724420516
    ), position = c(4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 
    5, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2), group = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L
    )), .Names = c("Mutation", "difference", "position", "group"
), row.names = c(11L, 2L, 19L, 10L, 9L, 21L, 20L, 12L, 16L, 13L, 
17L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 18L, 14L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use @cyclondude idea, and generlize it using `tapply` to create an adjust vector.

```
dat$group_adjust <- unlist(tapply(dat$group,dat$group,
       function(x) if(length(x)==1) 0
                   else seq(-length(x)/2,length(x)/2,length=length(x))))
```

The final plot looks like :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( dat,aes(x=factor(group),y=difference) ) +
  geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(Mutation)),stat="identity",
            position=position_dodge(height=0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Mutation, vjust = group_adjust,y=0),angle=90)+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  ylim(extendrange(dat$difference))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm still feel like I'm at the start of learning to use ggplot2 but maybe you can adapt what I've done to a plot that looks closer to what you want.  If anyone more experienced could direct me in a better style of coding for this problem I'd appreciate it.

```
n_in_group <- summary(as.factor(dat$group))
group_adjust <- c()
for(i in seq(n_in_group)) { 
  if(n_in_group[i] == 1)   {group_adjust <- c(group_adjust,0)         }
  if(n_in_group[i] == 2)   {group_adjust <- c(group_adjust,-1,1)  }
  if(n_in_group[i] == 3)   {group_adjust <- c(group_adjust,-1,0,1)}
}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( dat,aes(x=factor(group),y=difference) ) +
  geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(Mutation)),stat="identity",
            position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Mutation, vjust = group_adjust),angle=90)+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I tried to generalize your idea. You can see my answer. I had this idea in mind but I hoped to get more straight one. I will still wait for another approach or I will accept your solution.